# Database design for online mobile & mobile accessories shopping

Tags: mysql

hello i am creating database table design for online mobile shopping

1 mobile , mobile accessories

The flow of searching of mobile is mobile->brand->product
& flow of searching of mobile/accessories is accessories->categories->brand->product

I want to flow just as  filpkart. how should i create table structure of database?

Answer (score 0):

There is never a best way to do it, it all depends on the specifics of the project, what are you asking is an entire well payed profession.

If you want to get an idea, you will need to dive in to relational db tables, how they work and how to design.

As an example, in your specific case, you will have a table with mobilePhones one with brands one with accessories and one with categories. mobilePhones relates to brands 1to1 (faster for searches instead of having them both in one table) phones with accessories with onetomany and so on.